# invalid identifier while parsing json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, snowflake-schema, dbt

I am compiling a dbt base model. Currently I get this error below. Line 6 looks the same as other lines above. Might a small syntax error that I could not spot.

```
15:40:22  Database Error in model base_datacenter_handling_unit (models/l10_staging_datacenter/base_unit.sql)
15:40:22    000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 3
15:40:22    invalid identifier 'VALUE'
15:40:22    compiled SQL at target/run/dbt/models/l10_staging_datacenter/base_unit.sql
```

This is how my file looks like:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_DATA:"key"::text AS KEY 
    , value:"description"::text AS DESCRIPTION 
  , value:"globalHandlingUnitId"::text AS GLOBAL_HANDLING_UNIT_ID
  , value:"tareWeight"::NUMBER(38,0) AS TARTE_WEIGHT
  , value:"tareWeight_unit"::text AS TARTE_WEIGHT_UNIT
  , value:"width"::NUMBER(38,0) AS WIDTH
  , value:"width_unit"::text AS WIDTH_UNIT
  , value:"length"::NUMBER(38,0) AS LENGTH
    , value:"validFrom"::TIMESTAMP_NTZ AS VALID_FROM_TS_UTC
    , value:"validTo"::TIMESTAMP_NTZ AS VALID_TO_TS_UTC
    , value:"lastModified"::TIMESTAMP_NTZ AS LAST_MODIFIED_TS_UTC
  , value:"status"::text AS STATUS
    , md5(KEY::STRING || MASTERCLIENT_ID) AS HANDLING_UNIT_KEY --different logic than in POSTGRESDWH! 
    ,MASTERCLIENT_ID
    ,{{ extract_masterclientname_clause('META_FILENAME') }} AS MASTERCLIENT_NAME
    ,META_ROW_NUM
  ,META_FILENAME
  ,META_LOAD_TS_UTC
  ,META_FILE_TS_UTC
  ,CASE WHEN {{table_dedup_clause('HANDLING_UNIT_KEY')}} 
    THEN True
    ELSE False
  END AS IS_RECORD_CURRENT
FROM {{ source('INGEST_DATACENTER', 'HANDLING_UNIT') }} src
QUALIFY {{table_dedup_clause('HANDLING_UNIT_KEY')}}
```

It could also be because of the STRING type `md5(KEY::STRING || MASTERCLIENT_ID)`  I am using with md5 but I have another file, which is based on the same pattern but it does not throw an error tho:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_DATA:"issueId"::NUMBER(38,0) AS ISSUE_ID 
    , value:"slaName"::text AS SLA_NAME
    , value:"slaTimeLeft"::NUMBER(38,0) AS SLA_TIME_USED_SECONDS
    , md5(ISSUE_ID::STRING || SLA_NAME) AS ISSUE_SLA_ID  
    ,MASTERCLIENT_ID
    ,{{ extract_masterclientname_clause('META_FILENAME') }} AS MASTERCLIENT_NAME
    ,META_ROW_NUM
  ,META_FILENAME
  ,META_LOAD_TS_UTC
  ,META_FILE_TS_UTC
,CASE WHEN {{table_dedup_clause('ISSUE_SLA_ID')}}
    THEN True
    ELSE False
  END AS IS_RECORD_CURRENT
FROM {{ source('INGEST_EMS', 'ISSUES') }} src
    , lateral flatten ( input => JSON_DATA:slas)
QUALIFY {{table_dedup_clause('ISSUE_SLA_ID')}}
```

I don't see any significant difference between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is the output columns of a `FLATTEN` which you have in your second SQL. But not your first.

This is where putting an alias of every table, and using it on EVERY usage, you would see something like

```
SELECT t.json_data:"key",
   f.value:"json_prop_name"
FROM table AS t;
```

and be like, where does `f` come from...

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is the column is not named "tareWeight_unit". Snowflake creates column names in upper case regardless of how they are written *unless* the original create statement puts the columns names in double quotes (e.g. "MyColumn") in which case it will create the column names with the exact case specified. Use SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE  and check the actual column name.

Comment: I don't think its that because I am getting the same error, at the same position for multiple files within the same base model folder. Have you seen the answer above? That makes sense but I am not sure what I missed exactly